# Data Retrieval With three entities without using manual looping

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have three entities.

[image]

I need to retrieve all the lectures that teach a certain student. 
So far the solution i was able to come up is

first to use a subquery to retrieve all the courses the student takes by

> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
>   predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(students, $student, $ student.name ==
>   'student two').@count > 0"];

I execute the fetched request to obtain fetchedObjects.

Next i compare all the lecture objects with fetchedObjects. The lecture who conducts a course in fetchedObjects is the person who teaches the student in question.

Is there a much neater method of doing this without doing a comparison by hand ?
I mean can i do it using predicates alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch all lecturers that have a course with the given student, use the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(courses, $c, ANY $c.students.name == %@).@count > 0", studentName]
```

*Remark:* In your first example (fetch all courses for a student), you don't need a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY students.name == %@", studentName]
```

Comment: Is it not recommended to fetch all courses for a student by a SUBQUERY ?

Comment: @Crunch: I don't know why it should be recommended. "ANY" works fine with a single to-many relationship. "ANY" does not work with nested to-many relationships, that's why you have to use "SUBQUERY" as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrieve "Course" entity or "Lecturer" entities ?

for Course you could try this predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"students.name = %@",NAME];
```

now you have Course entities and you can get Lecturers too,

for Lecturers you could try

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY courses.@unionOfArrays.students.name = %@",NAME];
```

Comment: I received a "NSInvalidArgumentException reason to-many  key not allowed here" when i ran your 2nd query

Comment: updated , try NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY courses.students.name = %@",NAME];

Comment: Well not it gives me  "NSInvalidArgumentException reason multiple to-many key not allowed here"

Comment: do you have inverse relation too ?

Comment: Yes. I have two of them. As seen pictorially in the image posted above.

Comment: Okay , then use NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY courses.@unionOfArrays.students.name = %@",NAME];

Comment: Still a error pops out, this time "NSInvalidArgumentException reason Unsupported kvc aggregate in key path"

Comment: if Students is NSSet , please try @ unionOfSets instead of @ unionOfArrays

Comment: i got the same error. "NSInvalidArgumentException reason Unsupported kvc aggregate in key path"